# Sealing an envelope on shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, mail

On Shabbat, is it permissible to seal an envelope that does not require moistening, ie an envelope that has a PEEL & SEAL flap?

Comment: Wouldn't doing so be preparing for after Shabbat, even if it weren't a melacha?

Comment: @Scimonster Depends why you are sealing the envelope.

Answer (score 8):

[Rambam Hilchos Shabbos 10:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=12&perek=10&halocha=11&hilite=) says that gluing two pieces of paper together on Shabbos is a Toldah (offshoot) of Tofer (the biblical prohibition against sewing on Shabbos).

> המדבק ניירות או עורות בקולן של סופרים, וכיוצא בו--הרי זה תולדת תופר וחייב
>
> One who **glues pieces of paper** or leather to each other with scribe's glue (קולן של סופרים), **or anything similar** -- this is an offshoot of תופר, and he is liable for it.

Therefore I would conclude, that no matter the method of gluing (whether regular glue, regular envelopes, or "peel & seal" envelopes), gluing paper together is forbidden on Shabbos.

Comment: @Gershon - wouldn't separating the peel part from the glue also be some type of melacha - a form of tearing?

Comment: @DanF See that Rambam, the next thing he says in that halacha: "וכן המפרק ניירות דבוקין או עורות דבוקין ולא נתכוין לקלקל בלבד הרי זה תולדת קורע וחייב:"

Comment: @DanF: I was looking at it as if it was peeled prior to Shabbos and the only thing being done was sealing the envelope.